# R - Plotting data from a tapply output

Tags: r, tapply

I am working on a R project and I have some data in a data frame which I have used `tapply()` on.

```
res <- tapply(NEI$Emissions, NEI$year, sum)
```

Using tapply gives me the following output:

```
 1999    2002    2005    2008 
7332967 5635780 5454703 3464206
```

I want to plot the result from tapply with the years on the x-axis and the values on the y-axis. I have tried using the plot() function to do this:

```
plot(tapply(NEI$Emissions, NEI$year, sum))
```

However, the values on the x-axis from the plot function range from 1.0 - 4.0 (with intervals of 0.5). I would like to have the x-axis values be the years (1999, 2002, 2005, 2008). However, I am not sure how to do this.

Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output of `tapply` is an array, you can convert it to dataframe or use `aggregate` :

```
plot(aggregate(Emissions~year, NEI, sum))
```

If your `year` value is numeric it will give x-axis on continuous scale, you can convert it to factor.

```
temp <- aggregate(Emissions~year, NEI, sum)
temp$year <- factor(temp$year)
plot(temp)
```